# Magento 2 Custom Module Insert Data Issue not working

Tags: magento2, php, module, database, model

I want to save custom data from Ajax Request in my database but it's not working and not saving any data.

> namespace/Getquote/controller/index

```
<?php

namespace namespace\Getquote\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    )
    {
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }


    /**
     * Get A Quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
         if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()):
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $prod_sku = 'sku';//$data['prod_sku'];
            $email = 'test@mail.com';//$data['email'];
            $phone = '70123456';//$data['phone'];

            $__objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
            $model = $__objectManager->create('namespace\Getquote\Model\Quote');
            $model->setProductsku($prod_sku);
            $model->setCustomeremail($email);
            $model->setCustomerphone($phone);
            $model->save();
          endif;
    }
}
```

> namespace/Model/Quote

```
<?php
namespace namespace\Getquote\Model;
class Quote extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel 
{

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
            \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
            array $data = []
    ) 
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace\Getquote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote');
    }
}
```

> namespace/Model/ResourceModel/Quote

```
<?php
namespace namespace\Getquote\Model\ResourceModel;


class Quote extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace_getquote_quote', 'quote_id');
    }

}
```

> namespace/GetQuote/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Collection

```
<?php
namespace namespace\Getquote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'quote_id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'namespace_getquote_quote_collection';
    protected $_eventObject = 'quote_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('namespace\Getquote\Model\Quote', 'namespace\Getquote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote');
    }

}
```

> InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace namespace\Getquote\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (!$installer->tableExists('namespace_getquote_quote')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('namespace_getquote_quote')
            )
                ->addColumn(
                    'quote_id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary'  => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                    ],
                    'Quote ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'product_sku',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false,'default' => ''],
                    'Product SKU'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'customer_email',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false,'default' => ''],
                    'Email'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'customer_phone',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false,'default' => ''],
                    'Phone Number'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                    'Created At'
                )->addColumn(
                    'updated_at',
                    Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                    'Updated At')
                ->setComment('Quote Table')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Add your code block in try.....catch block. So If any error occured It show to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded your module and checked it for the same.

Below is the two mistakes with your module

1) **app/code/Codendot/Getquote/Model/ResourceModel**

you have given wrong tablename here(**codendot_getquote**) but your tablename should be(**codendot_getquote_quote**) like below , so replace your function with below one :

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('codendot_getquote_quote', 'quote_id');
    }
```

2) **app/code/Codendot/Getquote/Controller/Index**

You have given field name wrong over here , **give field name as below** :

```
$model->setProductSku($prod_sku);  // s of Sku should be captial same as for others - as you have given _(underscore) in setup script like product_sku
$model->setCustomerEmail($email); // same as above E capital of Email
$model->setCustomerPhone($phone); // same as above P capital of Phone
```

Try this , Its worked and data gets saved as well !!